# Nginx proxy based on SNI without decryption

Tags: nginx

I am currently using the following (simplified) configuration to proxy http and https connections over the same port (required by aws elastic beanstalk):

```
server {
    listen 777 ssl;
    server_name foo.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/foo.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/foo;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    error_page 418 = @upstream;
    error_page 497 = @upstream;

    location / {
        return 418;
    }

    location @upstream {
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

I want to change upstream to uwsgi and let uwsgi handle ssl because it would simplify deployment.

How can I adjust my configuration to work for SNI HTTPS and HTTP without Nginx decrypting the ssl traffic?

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do this, so that I can have nginx sitting in front of sniproxy - but it still seems that nginx won't read the sni address without trying to decrypt the traffic first. ("no ssl_certificate" errors in the log). :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**, you can't do with Nginx. By default, Nginx is always decrypting content, so Nginx can apply request routing. Some solution that can be tried:

- There are 3rd party module called [nginx_tcp_proxy_module](https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module). I haven't tried it yet. Because that module do proxy on network layer, so it will passing request without decryption.
- The preferred solution is use HAProxy. [This tutorial](http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/04/13/enhanced-ssl-load-balancing-with-server-name-indication-sni-tls-extension/) suggest that you can do TCP proxy with SNI capabilities.

---

### Sidenote

By default, Nginx always act as SSL offloading/decryption process on proxy. Here some the advantages doing SSL offloading (taken from [here](http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-ssl/))

- **Improved performance**
- **Better utilization of the backend servers**
- **Intelligent routing**
- **Certificate management**
- **Security patches**

Comment: I figured this was the case.  I just wanted to use nginx for this particular implementation instead of haproxy.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like this is now supported using the [ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html) module

Comment: I have also found [this Github-hosted article](https://gist.github.com/kekru/c09dbab5e78bf76402966b13fa72b9d2), which shows two different options of configuring nginx, including a transparent non-decrypting redirect. I have not tried it myself yet, but it seems likely to work

Answer (score 4):

There are some things you have to note about doing this:

- You're going to have to use a `stream` block rather than an `http` block, which means:
- You can't set `error_page` directives because HTTP error codes are at the application layer and you're not decrypting that layer
- You can't `proxy_pass` to an `http://` server because you're not doing SSL termination any more
- You can't `proxy_set_header` because you can't inject plaintext into an encrypted stream

If you accept those limitations and e.g. you're going to do the work in another server that is either the final destination or an intermediate proxy that is doing SSL termination, then here's what you need to do:

1. First, note that most nginx server configurations automatically wrap everything in an `http` block. So if e.g. you're used to just dropping a file into `/etc/nginx/conf.d` on Red Hat-type installs or `/etc/nginx/sites-available` with a symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` on Debian-type installs, that's not going to work here. You're going to have to make at least some minor changes to the root configuration file `/etc/nginx.conf`, if only to create a stream block that includes other files like this:

   ```
   stream {
       include /etc/nginx/stream.d/*.conf;
   }
   ```
2. Next, you need to create a stream server. You're limited to the directives that are in the `ngx_stream_*` modules, which excludes all the HTTP-specific stuff. As Robert Wagner's answer pointed out, you'll need to use the `ngx_stream_ssl_preread` module which doesn't exist in nginx versions older than 1.11.5. Create a file with the `.conf` extension in `/etc/nginx/stream.d`, or whatever other directory you chose, and define your servers. The following is taken verbatim from what's in the module documentation, and gives an example of SNI-based filtering (there's also ALPN and SSL version filtering available):

   ```
   map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
       backend.example.com      backend;
       default                  backend2;
   }

   upstream backend {
       server 192.168.0.1:12345;
       server 192.168.0.2:12345;
   }

   upstream backend2 {
       server 192.168.0.3:12345;
       server 192.168.0.4:12345;
   }

   server {
       listen      12346;
       proxy_pass  $name;
       ssl_preread on;
   }
   ```
3. Now, you have a server that doesn't decrypt traffic but does determine where to send it based on SNI. If a client connects and requests `backend.example.com` then it will be routed to `backend` and otherwise it will be routed to `backend2`.

There are other things you may want to consider as well, like setting `tcp_nodelay` or defining a stream `log_format` and enabling `access_log` for the `stream` block, but of course the format and variables will be different from an HTTP access log.