# Reverse proxy for RDP according to domain request

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, rdp

I have a scenario hope that someone will help me with that

So the scenario is i have a server that is reachable to the internet and some server that are connected to my lan (In the private network) so what i want is when some one try to connect to a domain in my network i want it to be redirected to another server in the private network

So what i want is
if in rdp whn.domain.com is stated than that should be to first the server exposed in the internet

than to the private ip ---> 192.168.71.1

similarly,

```
whm.domain.com ---> 192.168.71.2
whh.domain.com ----> 192.168.71.3
```

currently in my nginx.conf i have

```
stream {
    # ...
    server {
        listen     3389;
        proxy_pass 192.168.72.13:3389;
    }
}
```

so now what it is doing is any request to my server with port 3389 is redirected to one single ip

Now i want to check the domain that it has been pointing to and then tranfer it to that ip

i want something like

```
stream {
    # ...
    server {
        listen     3389;
        server_name whm.domain.com
        proxy_pass 192.168.71.1:3389;
    }
    server {
        listen     3389;
        server_name whn.domain.com
        proxy_pass 192.168.71.1:3389;
    }
}
```

But the stream context doesnt support server_name directive so any idea how can i achive this

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/628147/nginx-proxy-based-on-sni-without-decryption . Requires the relevant information to be carried in the TLS ClientHello message (so TLS encryption is mandatory for the method in the link).

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use the `map` directive and `ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module`:

```
stream {
    log_format basic '$remote_addr [$time_local] '
                     '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                     '$session_time';

    access_log  "/var/log/$ssl_preread_server_name-access.log" basic;
    error_log   "/var/log/$ssl_preread_server_name-error.log"  info;

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
        hostnames;
        # map ssl_preread_server_name to name
        whm.domain.com  192.168.71.1:3389;
        whn.domain.com  192.168.71.1:3389;
    }

    server {
        listen 3389;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass $name:$server_port;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
    }
}
```

with `map` you can use different backend servers and ports.